# Ending a tail -f on log files

Tags: tail

I have to kill the tail -f process after using it to tail log files.
Is there a way to end the process within the tail -f display of the logfile?

Comment: Does Ctrl+C not work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for the keystroke combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to stop the foreground process. See also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45025/how-to-suspend-and-bring-a-background-process-to-foreground).